# Parsing string to date in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to parse a date string using d3.js. The format is like `"2012-11-02T08:32:55-04:00"`

You can see the console output below.
Relavent API is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format).
D3 parser is stricter, as explains the doc. But, I was expecting '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' as the format string. Which returns null. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
format = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
format.parse("2012-11-02T08:32:55-04:00");
null
format.parse("2011-07-01T19:15:28Z");
Fri Jul 01 2011 19:15:28 GMT-0400 (EDT)
format = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z')
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z
format.parse("2011-07-01T19:15:28Z");
null
format.parse("2012-11-02T08:32:55-04:00");
null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that API:

> **The following directives are not yet supported for parsing**:
>   %j - day of the year.
>   %U - week number of the year.
>   %w - weekday number.
>   %W - week number of the year.
>   **%Z - time zone offset, such as "-0700".**
>   %% - a literal "%" character.

So you may be out of luck unless you remove the -[time_zone] part of the date.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer the case. Time zones were included in version 3.3.x of d3js.

d3js pull request: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/1495